# Anyone know what this symbol means?

Tags: egyptian, symbolism

Someone drew this symbol on my arm, and said it was an egyptian one and had some meaning, but I can't find it anywhere. The top that is obscured curls to the left.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like the [Adinkra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adinkra_symbols) ["Aya"](http://www.adinkra.org/htmls/adinkra/aya.htm) (fern) symbol:

[image: Adinkra Aya]

Adinkra is *not* Egyptian, though. It originates from the [Ashanti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashanti_people) and [Baoulé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baoul%C3%A9_people) peoples, in the neighborhood of Ghana and Côte d'Ivoire (respectively).

Comment: Yep, that was it!